# Running two Mysql docker containers

Tags: mysql, docker

I am trying to run two different mysql containers for master->slave replication. I start by building and running the master:

```
docker build --no-cache -t mysql-master .
docker run -it --name mysql-master -h mysql-master -p 3306:3309 mysql-master /bin/bash
```

Which works fine and runs the container correctly. I can get as far as getting the information to set up the second container, mysql-slave. When I run the following command:

```
docker build --no-cache -t mysql-slave .
docker run -it -p 3308:3309 mysql-slave --name mysql-slave --link mysql-master:mysql-slave /bin/bash
```

The mysql-master container disconnects. I am not sure why but I am sure that there is some kind of conflictions going on with the containers that I may not be aware of. Can anyone suggest what docker command I should be running so that both containers can run simultaneously?

I have a feeling this is because both containers are attempting to access the same port:

```
root@test2net:~# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
d1942b5e1f69        mysql-slave:latest    "/tmp/makeSlaveSQL.s   40 seconds ago      Up 40 seconds       3306/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32773->3307/tcp   mysql-slave
c9a7632d9cae        mysql-master:latest   "/tmp/makeMasterSQL.   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:32769->3306/tcp             mysql-master
```

Is there a way to explicitly cast each container to a specific port. I have tried using EXPOSE in the Dockerfile and the `-p` to designate different ports but as you can see from above, mysql-slave is still binding to port 3306.

Comment: It shouldn't really matter, but just pointing out that after you build your slave, you actually run `-d mysql-master` again. Again, it shouldn't matter and it's probably a typo/wrong copy paste.

Comment: Hmm I guess i will try it with the `-d` flag and try

Comment: Ok so i understand this: I have the workflow incorrect. I need to build the mysql-master, run it, build the slave, run it, then run the mysql-master again?

Comment: Your workflow is fine, I am just pointing out that you never run the `mysql-slave` in the commands you currently post. You only build it.

Comment: I am sorry, i saw the typo. Yes it is a typo and i do run both containers as part of the workflow. But I still run into issues with the containers running simultaenously

Comment: @ryekayo Did you solve this problem and how did you solve it? I also encountered this issue too.. running two different Mysql version 3 and 5. Thanks

Comment: If i remember correctly, the real issue was because the VM i was using did not have enough virtual RAM to support running multiple containers.